# How to re-add deleted columns from a dataframe in pandas python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-manipulation

How to re-add columns from original dataframe, which were once in the data frame but got removed using a list?

```
df_original =['a','b','c','d','f']
df_new=df_original[['b','c','d']]


user_re_add col=['a']

if user_re_add not in df_new.columns:
   add= df_new.append(user_re_add)
   print("Re-add the column from original df")
```

Expecting the df_new = ['a','b','c','d','f']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example:

```
df_original = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a','b','c','d','f'])
df_new=df_original[['b','c','d']]

user_re_add = df_original[['a']]

if [column for column in user_re_add.columns] not in [column for column in df_new.columns]:
    add = df_new.append(user_re_add)
    add = add[[column for column in df_original.columns if column in add.columns]]
    print("Re-add the column from original df")
```

Restoring the column deleted that was saved in a variable and reordering as the original frame.